# How to extract NavigableString from Python BeautifulSoup if HTML code contains line breaks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

*Note: question is slightly updated after the answer from [Brandon Stivers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67775510/4432107), since I realized I was not making myself clear.*

Hi I am trying to extract a NavigableString object from html.

The idea is to be able to further manipulate it with
`string.replace_with("new string")`

In the following example everything works fine

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p><b>my string</b></p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

soup.p.string.replace_with("New string")

print(soup)

# Output is '<p><b>New string</b></p>'
```

However if html code itself contains line breaks, then **NavigableString** is not extracted, instead a None is returned

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p>
    <b>my string</b>
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

soup.p.string.replace_with("New string")

print(soup)

# Output is: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace_with'
```

So, the question is how to extract a NavigableString, if html code contains line breaks. I know that `get_text(strip=True)` will work, but it will return just a text, not a **NavigableString**, so I will not be able to further manipulate it.

Note: in reality I need to manipulate data in the table, so example above is just to simplify the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're extracting data from a table, then why not provide the table?

Normally when parsing tables with BeautifulSoup, you read in the html from file or url (not by hard-coding it like you did). Unsure if the hard-coding on your part was an attempt at brevity.

Anyway, here's a working code example to answer your question. But for your actual use case (since it's not know what that really is), it may not work.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p>
    <b>my string</b>
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
strip = soup.find('p')

print(strip.text)

# Output is now 'my string'
```

The above is similar to how you would bring in a table to parse the information. You don't parse info from a table directly into a soup object. Below is an example from a current project of mine and how I am bringing in a table from a page with multiple tables. Note: I prefer to use lxml to parse tables as it does a better job at parsing complex tables.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(search.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ResultGrid'})

print(table)
```

I usually use pandas `pandas.read_html(str(table))` to grab the data ("my string"*) out of the table html produced above.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I have now slightly updated my question, since I realized I was not making myself clear. I need to extract a NavigableString object for the purpose of further manipulating it. Extracting of the text is not the goal.